# How do I find a list of stockholders of a public company listed in Canada?

Tags: stocks, canada, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges

How do i find all stockholders by holding percentage of a publicly listed company in Canada. Including minority stakeholders.

Comment: Individuals below the threshold of significant ownership [likely 10%?] will not have their information publicly available. What is it you are looking to determine?

Comment: i am trying to find the concentration of shares and is the management trying to obfscutae the share holding pattern by holding stocks through multiple numbered entities

Comment: That would be illegal; doesn't mean its impossible, but I would say pretty unlikely.

Comment: @kanduken - If they were holding stocks through "numbered entities", which I assume you mean shell companies, if the holdings were significant enough to require being reported, the shell companies would almost certainly not publicize their beneficial owners.  So you could maybe determine that Foo Shell Corp owns 15% of some company but you wouldn't be able to determine who owns or benefits from Foo Shell Corp.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as noted in the comments, appears to be that there is no reliable way of doing so.